# Swipe to dismiss for Android spinners

Tags: android, android-spinner, swipe-gesture

Is it possible to swipe to dismiss Android spinner items. If so, how? I can't seem to find resources online specifically for swipe to dismiss + spinners

Comment: You have to implement one yourself, but seing there isn't any tutorials/examples on this subject, it's probably not that straight-forward or at least no-one wants an implementation ;-)
Post the code, if you get around to creating one.
Also what do you need it for?

Comment: The user inputs information indirectly into a spinner. Every time the user submits info, the spinner grows creating a history. I wanted to use swipe to dismiss as a way to remove items from that history. As I'm just starting out on Android, I doubt I'll be creating one anytime soon, but I'll post it if I get around to it.

Comment: Why don't you just use a custom view for every row and add a button to the row, which deletes the row clicked on? Its also less intuitive to swipe to dismiss inside a spinner in my opinion ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right about how it's less intuitive for swipe to dismiss on spinners. I was unaware of custom views, but for anyone interested I used this site: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/07/18/customizing-a-spinner-in-android/ and got it to set up a custom view that had a delete button.